# Update of two same tables on different oracle schemas using primary key

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

I am scratching our head to resolve the issue with good performance, we managed to find out the solution in java by using hash map, but as the table contains 1L records its pretty tough to manage this part.

I am looking for the best possible option.

I have two schemas on same oracle database. I need to update a table with another schema table using primary key(we need only update if the primary key row exists, we should not insert it).

Suppose My oracle database is TEST and i have two schema's SCHEMA1 & SCHEMA2.

SCHEMA1 & SCHEMA2 CONTAINS THE TABLE SAMPLE1

Structure:

```
ID NUMBER ==> PRIMARY KEY
NAME VARCHAR ==> PRIMARY KEY
LASTNAME VARCHAR ==> NORMAL COLUMN
```

NOW SCHEMA1  SAMPLE1 CONTAINS DATA BELOW

```
1) 123 'TEMP' 'TEMPOARY1'
2) 234 'TEMP2' 'TEMPORARY2'
3) 345 'TEMP3' 'TEMPORARY3'
```

SCHEMA2  SAMPLE1 CONTAINS DATA BELOW

```
1) 123 'TEMP' 'TEMP1'
2) 23   'TEMP23 'TEMP2'
3) 235 'TEMP2' 'TEMP3'
```

Now my target is i need to sync table SAMPLE1 of SCHEMA1 with the table of SAMPLE1 of SCHEMA2 and the result should be below.

```
1) 123 'TEMP' 'TEMP1'
2) 234 'TEMP2' 'TEMPORARY2'
3) 345 'TEMP3' 'TEMPORARY3'
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Use a `MERGE` statement. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
 declare

   procedure fncUpdate(pId PLS_INTEGER, pName VARCHAR2 , pLastname VARCHAR2) as
   vIden pls_integer;    
   begin
     UPDATE SCHEMA2.SAMPLE1 set  id, name,lastname  values (pId, pName pLastname)
     returning iden into vIden;

     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('iden : '|| vIden);      
   end fncUpdate;

 begin
    for cur in(
        SELECT id,name,lastname
        FROM  SCHEMA1.SAMPLE1    
      ) 
      loop
        fncUpdate(cur.id,cur.name,cur.lastname);
      end loop;
 end;
```

Comment: Why PL/SQL? Never do it in PL/SQL when you could do it in SQL. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Update of two same tables on different oracle **databases**
>
> I have two **schemas**

I have edited your question title and changed database to schema. Since, you have clearly mentioned schema in your question body. Do not confuse between a **DATABASE** and a **SCHEMA**. I have seen SQL Server developers often interpreting a schema as a relative term for database. **A schema is the set of objects (tables, views, indexes, etc) that belongs to an user. Do not confuse between a schema and database.**

No need of PL/SQL. Do it in plain SQL.

You could use a **MERGE** statement.

For example,

```
MERGE INTO schema2.table2 t2
  USING (SELECT * FROM schema1.table1) t1
ON (t2.primarykey = t1.key)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
t2.column2 = t1.column2
AND t2.column3 = t1.column3
/
```